# Setting up touch ID - "unable to complete Touch ID setup"

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, bug, touch-bar, touch-id

I've had some problems recently with my Macbook on OSX (newest Macbook version with touch bar). Where my Touch ID used to work, suddenly, one day two things happened:

1. My computer have started to start much slower (2-3minutes+)
2. Touch Id does not work before

I've tried to go into Touch Id under "System Preferances". I've removed the existing fingerprint. When I click "Add a fingerprint", enter the password, it goes directly to "Failed - Unable to complete Touch ID setup".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by simply doing a hard reinstall of everything. I haven't had this problem now since September.

After spending hours(!) on the phone with the Apple support, I simply ended up with a full re-install. That included starting OSX up in the recovery mode, full format and downloading a new version of the OSX operating system.

Not a very elegant solution, but at least my computer has been without problems since.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have synmatec or any antivirus installed? If so, uninstall them and restart your system, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue like described here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/384410

**TL;DR:**

Opened a Terminal and run:

```
diskutil apfs list
```

This showed a volume described as "VM" with an error -69461

Then run (replace disk1s4_changeme with your VM volume):

```
diskutil apfs eraseVolume disk1s4_changeme -name VM
```

Check that the Volume war recreated and the error is gone:

```
diskutil apfs list
```

Then set the role to VM again (the "V" has to be uppercase!):

```
diskutil apfs chrole disk1s4_changeme V
```

Check the list output:

```
diskutil apfs list
```

You should see something like

```
APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s4 (VM)
```

That's it. Now the Touch ID worked for me again!
Thanks to [Henrik N](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/8902/henrik-n)